# What kind of car was Derek Hale driving in "Lunar Ellipse"?

Tags: teen-wolf

I am not very familiar with the various car makes that exist, but am interested in one from [Lunar Ellipse (S3E12)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3089166/?ref_=ttep_ep13) of Teen Wolf.

**What kind of car did Derek drive when escaping with Cora in that episode?**

Comment: No'it looks like a jeep but it's much better

Comment: In a show where everyone's really closely looking out for the supernatural, you'd think the cast would notice that **everyone drives a Toyota**. How weird is that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Teen Wolf Wikia](http://teenwolf.wikia.com/wiki/Lunar_Ellipse) identifies this car as an [**FJ Cruiser**](http://www.toyota.com/fjcruiser/), one of several Toyota vehicles added to the show as part of an extensive product placement deal.

**Episode Screenshot**
[image]

**FJ Cruiser [promotional image](http://www.toyota.com/fjcruiser/)**
[image]

**As seen on screen**
[image]